# jQuery ScrollSpy only highlighting for part of scrolled section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery ScrollSpy to apply a `.underlined` class to some navigation links when the `<div>` in question selected by `id` is currently scrolled to. The code I have at the moment isn't working for the second two sections, and the first section which it is working for it only applies the `.underlined` class to `#tenantsandowners_link` for a little part of the `#tenantsandowners` `div`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tenantsandowners').scrollspy({
                min: $('#tenantsandowners').offset().top,
                onEnter: function(element, position) {
                    $("#tenantsandowners_link").addClass('underlined');
                },
                onLeave: function(element, position) {
                    $("#tenantsandowners_link").removeClass('underlined');
                }
            });
            $('#payment').scrollspy({
                min: $('#payment').offset().top,
                onEnter: function(element, position) {
                    $("#payment_link").addClass('underlined');
                },
                onLeave: function(element, position) {
                    $("#payment_link").removeClass('underlined');
                }
            });
            $('#paymentpage').scrollspy({
                min: $('#paymentpage').offset().top,
                onEnter: function(element, position) {
                    $("#paymentpage_link").addClass('underlined');
                },
                onLeave: function(element, position) {
                    $("#paymentpage_link").removeClass('underlined');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Here is the related markup:

```
<div class="pull-right interlinks">
    <a href="#tenantsandowners" id="tenantsandowners_link" class="interlink">Tenants & Property Owners</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#payment" id="payment_link" class="interlink">Payment Options</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#paymentpage" id="paymentpage_link" class="interlink">Personalised Payment Page</a>
</div>

<div id="tenantsandowners">
    <div class="container">
        <center><h2>Tenants and Property Owners</h2></center>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img style="margin-bottom:-30px;" src="/assets/img/businessman.jpg" width="100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <br>
                <ul class="lead fa-ul">
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Pay and receive your Rent and Maintenance charges</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Instant or Schedule Payment</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Multiple Payment options with different currencies</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Pay from around the world</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Have fastest settlements</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> All in single account</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="/signup/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised">GET STARTED NOW</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="payment">
    <div class="container">
        <center><h2>Payment Options</h2></center>
        <br>
        <div class="row" id="">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <ul class="fa-ul lead pull-right">
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Domestic & International Payment Option</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Highly Secured Environment</li>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> Multiple Payment Gateways</li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <span class="well lead hidden-xs hidden-sm pull-right" style="color:black;">
                    Credit Card / Debit Card / Net Banking / PayPal
                </span>
                <span class="well hidden-lg hidden-md pull-right" style="color:black;">
                    Credit Card / Debit Card / Net Banking / PayPal
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img class="paymentimage" src="assets/img/visa.png" /><br>
                    <img class="paymentimage" src="assets/img/mastercard.png" /><br>
                    <img class="paymentimage" src="assets/img/maestro.png" /><br>
                    <img class="paymentimage" src="assets/img/amex.png" /><br>
                    <img class="paymentimage" src="assets/img/paypal.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="paymentpage">
    <div class="container">
        <center><h2>Personalised Payment Page</h2></center>
        <br>
        <div class="row" id="">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <center>
                    <img src="/assets/img/iphone.png" />
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <br>
                <p class="lead">Create in 2 Minutes</p>
                <p class="lead">Property Owners, Builders, Owners Associations<br>can create your own payment collection page to<br>receive the rent and maintenance charges.</p>
                <br>
                <p class="lead">Use your own Logo, Company Name and make<br> your personalised one stop instant payment page<br>with multiple payment gateways. <a href="/personalised-payment-page/">Full Benefits</a></p>
                <div style="position: absolute; text-align:center;">
                    <a href="/personalised-payment-page/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-raised" style="max-width: 300px !important;">CREATE YOURS NOW</a><br>
                    <b style="color: #388e3c;">(FREE - LIMITED PERIOD)</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you also upload some of the HTML markup that this is applied to. Thanks.

Comment: @AlvinPascoe I've added it :)

Comment: I think I've figured out your problem, check my answer and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is due to using **multiple `scrollspy` instances**.

None of the examples on the authors website seem to use multiple instances and I've seen issues like this before.

I solved the problem by using only one instance of `scrollspy` and changing the script to be mostly dynamic.

Here is a fiddle - I included the jquery-scroll plugin directly on the page so your JavaScript code **starts from line: 100** (I also left in some comments so you can play around with it):

http://jsfiddle.net/16m79c35/

(**Fiddle with padding**: http://jsfiddle.net/7q26hptu/)

(Fiddle with padding **and a fixed header**: http://jsfiddle.net/05akLpj6/)

I used [this example](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy/blob/master/examples/colors.html) on the authors website and edited it to suit your needs.

Let me know if this solves your problem :)

---

Note: This script can decoupled further from your content by replacing the static ID selectors on line: 106 `$('#tenantsandowners, #payment, #paymentpage')` with a class of say `$('.scrollspy')` and adding this class to the previously mentioned `div` elements alongside their IDs. I haven't tested it but it should work fine.

Comment: @James - No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: I have padding on my #tenantsandowners, #payment, #paymentpage elements, how do I include the padding in the scrollspy detectable area?

Comment: This solution does not actually work, please see my example at http://rentgive.jamesallison.co/

Comment: @James - To account for padding, try to change the JavaScript reference from `height()` to `innerHeight()` (on line:113 of my fiddle).

Comment: @James - Apart from that, how else is the example not working?

Comment: I've just tried to change it to `innerHeight()`, still not working

Comment: @James - try `outerHeight()`. Is the padding issue the only issue? Is that what you're trying to solve?

Comment: @James - also ensure that `#tenantsandowners`, `#payment` and `#paymentpage` have relative positioning... I've updated my fiddle with paddings: http://jsfiddle.net/hq6gcfoa/

Comment: My code is identical to the one in your fiddle, yet it still is not working. Do you have any more ideas? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @James - Update your live example with `innerHeight()` (Capital 'H') instead of `height()` and I'll take a look. Change `max: position.top + $(this).height() - 1,` into `max: position.top + $(this).innerHeight() - 1,`

Comment: @James - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/05akLpj6/ - I think your issues are due to the height of the fixed header. You need to take that into account when calculating when to change the `underlined` class.

Comment: Thank you very much, think everything is fine now